# How do you get your app on BlackBerry's App Store "Featured" section?

Tags: web-applications, blackberry, blackberry-world

How do you get your application on the Featured section in the BlackBerry app world?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When one of our applications was featured in the BlackBerry App World, we were contacted by RIM directly.

However, RIM has a section in their [BlackBerry App World FAQ](http://us.blackberry.com/developers/appworld/faq.jsp) which addresses this:

**Can I nominate my application to be featured in the Featured Items section on BlackBerry App World?**

Yes. To nominate your application, you must send an email to **blackberryappworldmarketing@rim.com** with the following information:

- Vendor name
- Application name
- Target region for application content
  (ex. Global, North America, Canada
  etc.)
- Spotlight image (attached to email)
- Spotlight description (attached to
  email)

**What are the requirements for the Spotlight Image?**

The Spotlight Image must meet the following specifications:

- Dimensions: 340 x 340 pixels
- Bit Depth: 24-bit RGB
- File Format: PNG
- Edges not rounded off

**What are the requirements for the Spotlight Description?**

The Spotlight Description must meet the following specifications:

- Length: under 50 characters
- File Format: TXT

Translations: you must provide an English Spotlight Description. In addition to English, you must provide a translation of the Spotlight Description for each of the languages supported by your nominated application

**What factors are taken into consideration when selecting feature applications?**

The following items are considered when selecting feature applications:

- Vendor account must be in good
  standing
- Application must be Up for Sale
- Positive user reviews and application
  rating (3+ star rating)
- Vendor participation on BlackBerry
  App World (number of applications in
  BlackBerry App World, forum
  participation etc.)
- End-user context (regional events,
  holidays etc.)
- BlackBerry App World co-marketing
  (use of the Get it at BlackBerry App
  World logo)

**When will I know if my application will be featured?**

In the event your application is selected to be featured, you’ll be contacted (via email provided in nomination) 1-4 weeks prior to feature placement.